# Blank screen with navbar in Ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to test out my app by using the app Ionic View. Unfortunately all I see is a blank screen with a blue navbar header.

I have uploaded my app using ionic upload. Then I have synced my app in Ionic View and finally I press 'View app'. I see the Ionic loading animation and then I just see a white screen with a blue navbar header.

My app uses a blue navbar header, so it is loading something.

When I run my app in the browser or when I debug it using a USB-cable and live debug on my phone, everything is just working fine. So why isn't it possible to use my app using Ionic View?